# How to use python logging setLoggerClass?

Tags: python, logging, customization

I want to add a custom logger to a python application I am working on. I think that the logging module intends to support this kind of customization but I don't really see how it works with the typical way of using the logging module. Normally, you would create a logger object in a module like,

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

However, somewhere in the application, probably the entry-point, I will have to tell the logging module to use my logger class,

```
logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)
```

However, this is often going to be called after modules have been imported and the logger objects are already allocated. I can think of a couple of ways to work around this problem (using a manager class to register logger allocations or calling getLogger() for each log record -- yuk), but this does not feel right and I wanted to know what the right way of doing this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any logging initialisation / settings / customisation should be done before the application code runs. You can do this by putting it in the `__init__.py` file of your main application directory (this means it'll run before any of your modules are imported / read).

You can also put it in a `settings.py` module and importing that module as the first thing in your application. As long as the logging setup code runs before any `getLogger` calls are made then you're good.

Comment: Argh. Typically, I have not actually used the \_\_init\_\_.py file for initialization, just for package structure and importing convenient functions. It seems pretty obvious that it is the right place for initialization code :) However, one of the logging handlers I want to add to the logger is a file handler so that has a log path that the user can specify from the command line. I guess I could add that as a class variable that can pass on changes to instances, but I am don't feel that's a great way of doing it because it creates a race condition.

Comment: After a little experimentation, I think I understand. Previously, I was installing the handlers as a part of the logger initialization, which I think is the wrong thing to do. I have move the handler addition into the entry-point code, which avoids any race condition on the file handler and ensures that modules using logging.getLogger() get the customized class as I wanted. Thanks for your help!